# Discord.py bot doesn't recognize commands from cogs

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to figure out how cogs work with the discord.py rewrite and I managed to get a bot working with only one cog. The problem is, the bot recognizes commands from one cog, but not the other.

importing the cogs in `bot.py`

```
cogs = [
'cogs.basic',
'cogs.mod']

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Arthur Morgan")
    print("version: "+version)
    game = discord.Game("rebuilding.....")
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=game)
    for extension in cogs:
        bot.load_extension(extension)
        return
```

inside `basic.py` commands inside here seem to work

```
   import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Basic(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name='ping', aliases=['p'])
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Pong! :ping_pong:")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Basic(bot))
```

commands in `mod.py` output [this](https://pasteboard.co/IGfkHzV.png)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Mod(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def pong(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Ping!")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Mod(bot))
```

does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Please add the code directly instead of linking to images of it. Thanks.

Comment: i'm sorry, i changed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for extension in cogs:
    bot.load_extension(extension)
    return
```

The coroutine stops when it reaches `return`, after loading only one cog.